# Execute all javascript functions in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a function which will execute all my functions in the sequence they wrote in ExecuteINsequence function. I want a generic ExecuteINsequence function to which i will pass any 3 functions which should be executed one after other.

```
ExecuteINsequence(functionOne, [p1, p2], functionTwo, [p1, p2], functionThree, [p1, p2]);

function ExecuteINsequence(f1, f1_params, f2, f2_params, f3, f3_params) {
  f1.apply(this, f1_params);
  f2.apply(this, f2_params);
  f3.apply(this, f3_params);
}

function functionOne(p1, p2) {
  console.log("one");
  $.ajax({
      url: "www.url.com",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        functionFour()
      );
    }
  });
}

function functionTwo(p1, p2) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("two");
  }, 2000);

}

function functionThree(p1, p2) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("three");
  }, 1000);
}

function functionFour() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("four");
  }, 3000);

}
```

expected Result:
one
four
two
three
Actual reuslt:
one
three
two
four

Comment: They will execute in the order you invoke them.  Given that you are doing asynchronous logic in them (ajax and timeouts), the order in which they **finish** is not guarenteed.  Which is an entirely different question.

Comment: Given the functions you've provided that "can't be changed", this task is impossible. To enforce order, you must be able to determine when the function is done doing what it needs to do. If the function performs an async task that you want to finish before continuing, it must either return a promise or accept a callback.

Comment: If they all returned promises, you could easily just do `await` for each one inside an async function, or a .then chain. For callbacks, you could do that iteratively.

Comment: You'll have to cache the results in all the various ways that might happen (Promise, callback, async/await, sync, etc) - then iterate the results.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because while your functions are in order, they perform async actions (the ajax and set timeout call).

The functions all get *started* in the right order, but due to their timings *end* in another. If you add a `console.log` as first line in your functions (and not in the onComplete's as they now are), you'll see they start in the order you expect.

For the ajax-request, that is whats called a Promise. It will always do *something* at the end, but you have to "connect" to it:

```
function functionOne(p1, p2) {
  console.log("one");
  return $.ajax({
      url: "www.url.com",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        functionFour()
      );
    }
  });
}

functionOne(1,2).then(functionTwo);
```

You might also want to check out the `async` + `await` combination. Promises and async matter can get complex very quickly, so I recommend doing a little more research at those topics to clear things up. It takes a few times to understand them.

Comment: Jquery's ajax does not return a promise. It does however return an object with a `then` method that is not compatible with promses (it uses `ajax.then(okCallback,errorCallback)` instead of `promise.then().catch()`. But if you want to use `.then()` you must not use `success: function()`

Answer (score -1):

Callbacks is what allows asynchronous functions to continue processing in sequence. This is true for all languages: c++ (lambda callbacks), Java (lambda callbacks and CompletionStage), go, Python etc. - not just for javascript.

So to solve this you need to do the following:

```
ExecuteINsequence(functionOne, [p1, p2], functionTwo, [p1, p2], functionThree, [p1, p2]);

function ExecuteINsequence(f1, f1_params, f2, f2_params, f3, f3_params) {
  var self = this;

  f1.apply(this, f1_params,function(){
    // self is necessary in here because we are no
    // longer calling f2 in the context of ExecuteINsequence():
    f2.apply(self, f2_params,function(){
      // same reasoning for self:
      f3.apply(self, f3_params);
    });
  });
}

function functionOne(p1, p2, callback) {
  console.log("one");
  $.ajax({
      url: "www.url.com",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        functionFour(callback)
      );
    }
  });
}

function functionTwo(p1, p2,callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("two");
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback();
    }
  }, 2000);

}

function functionThree(p1, p2, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("three");
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function functionFour(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("four");
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback();
    }
  }, 3000);

}
```

Alternatively, if you are using promises you can use `async`/`await`:

```
ExecuteINsequence(functionOne, [p1, p2], functionTwo, [p1, p2], functionThree, [p1, p2]);

async function ExecuteINsequence(f1, f1_params, f2, f2_params, f3, f3_params) {
  await f1.apply(this, f1_params);
  await f2.apply(self, f2_params);
  await f3.apply(self, f3_params);
}

function functionOne(p1, p2) {
  console.log("one");
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "www.url.com",
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        functionFour(resolve)
      )
    });
  });
}

function functionTwo(p1, p2) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("two");
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function functionThree(p1, p2) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("three");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function functionFour(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("four");
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback();
    }
  }, 3000);
}
```

You may have noticed that all asynchronous functions in the javascript world either accept a callback, return a promise or have some weird, non-standard mechanism of passing a callback like `$.ajax()` `success` property - that's why they exist - to allow you to sequence function calls.